# Como fazer uma contagem de registros (SELECT COUNT) em Linq

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

Como fazer uma contagem de registros que uma consulta retornaria em Linq (Entity Framework) em C#? O equivalente em SQL é fazer um `SELECT COUNT(*)`.

Note que eu quero receber já direto a contagem de registros, assim como um SELECT COUNT(*) faria, e não receber os resultados e fazer uma contagem depois. Então um `.Select().Count()` ou um `.Where().Count()` não resolve a minha situação. Nem isso:

```
var result = from tbl in tabela
             select tabela;
int contagem = result.Count();
```

Como seria pra realizar outras operações em uma consulta só, por exemplo: Min, Max, ou operações aritméticas entre duas consultas (ex: `SELECT(...)/SELECT COUNT(*)`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apesar dos comandos estarem em linhas separadas no C#, somente será feita uma consulta no banco de dados no momento que você chamar o método `Count()`.

Esse código **faz apenas uma query**:

```
var result = from tbl in tabela
             select tabela; // nenhuma query será executada

int contagem = result.Count(); // a query será executada aqui
```

Comment: A minha dúvida é no funcionamento da função `.Count()` (bem como nos métodos similares da classe `Enumerable`). Ele não opera em variáveis que já contenham coleções de dados (Listas)? Porque pelo tamanho da tabela que estou consultando, eu não posso guardar os resultados em uma variável para depois contar o número de registros dessa variável.

Comment: Quando estiver usando Linq-to-entities, os métodos **não estaram** sobre o `IEnumerable` **mas sim sobre um `IQueryable`**... é por isso que o select com `COUNT(*)` só é executado quando o método `Count()` for chamado.

Comment: Lembrando que um `IQueryable` é um `IEnumerable`. O motivo pelo qual o `Count` é executado imediatamente é porque ele não tem execução diferida. Você recebe como retorno direto o resultado `int`, ao invés de um `IQueryable`

Comment: Entendi! Muito obrigado aos dois!

Comment: O que eu quis dizer é que o método `Count()` sendo chamado é um específico do `IQueryable`. É um extension-method existente na classe `System.Linq.Queryable`. Se você tentar usar o método `System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(enumerable)` e passar o objeto, então a query será executada trazendo todos os registros, e depois será feita a contagem.

Comment: Ou seja, não faça isso: `(result as IEnumerable<T>).Count()`

Answer (score 4):

Basicamente pra você entender, enquanto a lista que você estiver consultando for um `IQueryable` e o Entity Framework não tiver executado nenhuma consulta ao banco de dados o EF tentará converter a sua query em uma expressão SQL.

Se você estiver utilizando a versão 6 do Entity Framework uma boa alternativa é sempre exibir as queries SQL executadas pelo framework, dessa forma por exemplo:

```
var db = new DataContext(); //sua instância da implementação DbContext
db.Database.Log = (s) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(s); // essa linha seta que o log gerado pelo EF6 será exibido no Output do Visual Studio
var c = db.Produtos.Sum(m => m.PrecoCusto); // essa consulta será executada conforme sua pergunta, com um SUM(campo) na query SQL
```

Checando o `Database.Log` você conseguirá entender naturalmente quais são e quando o EF executa de fato uma query no banco de dados.